# calling the Execute method of IExternalLateBoundService

Tags: mdriven

The question about the calling of the custom .net method implemented in the TurnKey_ExternalLateBound.dll.

I remember that it worked for me, but it was long time ago.

I tried [this article](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Calling_your_own_c_-_sharp_.net_things_from_Turnkey%E2%80%93server_side) and I put simple code:

```
public IElement Execute(IClassifier classifier, IObject theobject, IMethod method, IModifiableVariableList variableList)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

But I got nothing in the Turnkey. The tagged value of the class's method is ok. Viewmodel's action column calls this method.

Could you please advise what should I do else?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am only aware of the steps you lay out - are you putting the assembly in the folder EXT_LateBoundAssembly in the application root?
There is a /Log in the turnkey app directory - check it.

Comment: Yes, the dll is in the EXT_LateBoundAssembly folder. Will try on different pc. And no errors in the log. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works! Seems that it was fixed when I put Eco.Handles.dll and Eco.Interfaces.dll in to the EXT_LateBoundAssembly folder.
+ log file shows me the exception
Thanks a lot!